# Unit test always fail when class is run

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

when I run this class, I'm always got test failed in method `verify_on_success_is_called()` with error,

**Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.**

but if I run method only, test will passed.

```
@Mock
lateinit var mDummy: Dummy

private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

@Mock
lateinit var main: MainViewModel.IMain

@Before
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    MainViewModel.mIMain = main
    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
    mainViewModel = MainViewModel(mDummy)
}

@Test
fun verify_on_success_is_called() {
    val mockList: ArrayList<Employee> = ArrayList()
    mockList.add(Employee(1, "a", 20000.0, 22))
    val list: List<Employee> = mockList
    `when`(mDummy.getEmployees()).thenReturn(Observable.just(Response.success(list)))
    mainViewModel.getEmployees()
    Mockito.verify(main, times(1)).onSuccess()
}

@Test
fun verify_on_onError_is_called() {
    MainViewModel.mIMain = main
    `when`(mDummy.getEmployees()).thenReturn(Observable.error(Throwable()))
    mainViewModel.getEmployees()
    Mockito.verify(main, times(1)).onError()
}
```

this the viewModel class I want to test

```
class MainViewModel(private val mDummy: Dummy) : ViewModel() {

companion object {
    lateinit var mIMain: IMain
}

interface IMain {
    fun onSuccess()
    fun onError()
}

fun getEmployees() {
    mDummy.getEmployees()
        .observeOn(SchedulerProvides.main())
        .subscribeOn(SchedulerProvides.io())
        .subscribe({ response ->
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                mIMain.onSuccess()
            } else {
                mIMain.onError()
            }
        }, {
            mIMain.onError()
        })
}
```

and this my mainActivity 
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    MainViewModel.mIMain = mIMainViewModelIniliazed()
}

private fun mIMainViewModelIniliazed() = object :MainViewModel.IMain{
    override fun onSuccess() {

    }

    override fun onError() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move code from  setup() to the tests

Comment: @Eugene can you give me more explanation why I must change setup from `@Before` to `@Test`?

Comment: I did not say you should switch Before to Test. To understand the issue I recommend to remove fun setup() and initialize everything in tests. Now, you initialize MainViewModel. miMain in 2 setup and test. You also use global objects, their state is shared between all the test, so it’s hard to track the state at any point of time

Comment: Later, when you fix the issue you can remove fun setup

Comment: `setup()` used to initialized the mock, viewmodel,and etc. so delete it is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if am wrong but i think your problem is because you're setting

```
MainViewModel.mIMain = main
```

before creating your viewmodel instance, shouldn't be as below?

```
mainViewModel = MainViewModel(mDummy)
mainViewModel.mIMain = main
```

Comment: my method `verify_on_onError_is_called()` is still pass the test.
`MainViewMode.mImain = main` is used to initialized interface from activity to viewModel. so this not the problem.

Comment: @Alibana Thats not true - your class can have a default behavior to return `onError` when null / nothing / any exception is returned or triggered. Consider this answer and try it out.

Comment: I'm already change the code, and add listener from another method. still get same error. I'm already add my full code to now.